# Find the fixed points of the action

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

Let $T$ be the set of all invertible diagonal matrices of determinant one. How can I find out the fixed points and $1$-dimensional orbits of $T \times T$ action on $\mathbb{CP}^3$ given by $(A,B)\cdot X = AXB^{-1}$ where $X$ denotes the matrix representation of an element of $\mathbb{CP}^3$.

In fact, when I take the matrix with only one nonzero entry, they are fixed point but I don't know if there are any other fixed points. Is there any way to compute all the fixed points? I do not have any idea about how to find out the $1$-dimensional orbits.

Are there any notes/books about this question which you recommend?

Comment: You can read http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help for some help on formatting, and here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference on how to type math

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions. I will work on it.